# Creating Team using a service principal

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Using the [PowerShell module for Microsoft Teams 0.9.5](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MicrosoftTeams/0.9.5) we are authenticating successfully using a registered Application Principal and a certificate.

When trying to perform creation of a new Team using the `New-Team` cmdlet,

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -TenantId $TenantId -ApplicationId $AppClientId -CertificateThumbprint $cert.Thumbprint

New-Team -DisplayName "Team1" -Alias "Team1" -AccessType Public -AddCreatorAsMember $false
```

it always returns error as below

```
New-Team : Error occurred while executing
Code: InvalidRequest
Message: Team owner not found for e41cce9d-7e7e-45c9-979e-1b30a1c7e1cf.
InnerError:
  RequestId: 50db5055-288b-407d-bb76-e3e50054631c
  DateTimeStamp: 2018-11-13T08:28:31
HttpStatusCode: InvalidRequest
```

Creating a new Team/Group via this module, which uses Office Graph APIs behind the scenes, is stated as supported by the official documentation

> *Examples of group features that support delegated **and app-only permissions**:*
>
> *- Creating and deleting groups*

From:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/known_issues

Answer (score 1):

The Teams Graph APIs support application permissions, the Teams PowerShell cmdlets do not. The logic for acquiring a token is different for user delegated versus application permissions.

Comment: I have tried 're-playing' the creation of a new Team, replacing the access token with that one acquired for a service principal; but the end result has been that I only have an half-baked Exchange object, and nothing in Teams

Comment: new-team makes two different Graphical -- one to create group, a second to put a team in it. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/teams-create-group-and-team describes how to do this.